# Taking off tefillin for Mussaf on Rosh Chodesh

Tags: tefilla, sources-mekorot, tefilin, rosh-chodesh-new-month, musaf

On Rosh Chodesh we take off our *tefillin* before *Mussaf*.

1) What's the source this?

2) Why do we do it?

Comment: @IsaacMoses - I knew that it was discussed before but couldn't find it. Any general tricks to locating possible dupes?

Comment: @DanF While posting the question, a list of questions related to the text you're typing in shows up. After a question has been posted, an automatically-generated list of "Related" questions shows up on the right. I found this duplicate in there.

Comment: @IsaacMoses - Hmmm ... I know that system. Perhaps, in this case, I didn't type the correct words for the search

Comment: @DanF, you didn't post this question, did you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Orach Chaim 423:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49626&st=&pgnum=181) is the source. Mishna Berura 10 explains that it is like Yom Tov, where Yom Tov is an Os, the same is by Rosh Chodesh when we say the special Musaf you take it off.

Comment: Specifically, the Os is one of the korban mussaf, which is why we take it off before mussaf, and DON'T take it off for Purim or Channukah, which had no extra korbanos.

Comment: You voted to close as a dupe and answered anyway? Why?

Comment: @DoubleAA: I answered it before I realized there was a dupe.